# Call download lua script in app

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to develop a game by using the c++ with lua, and I am using the quick-cocos2d-x engine to help me finish that.
The problem is:
I need user to download the lua scripts into their sdcard on their iphone/android devices, so that I can call the function in the downloaded lua scripts, but I am not sure for how to implement that?

What I have done but failed:

1. Modified the main.lua:

   `package.path = package.path .. ";src/"
   to be: 
   package.path = package.path .. ";sdcard/scripts/"`
2. In my lua script(internal), call the downloaded script by using:

   `local testScene = require("sdcard.scripts.DownloadTestScene")
   display.replaceScene(testScene.new())`

So do anyone know how to make it come true, I have the internal lua script, I just want to call the download lua script, and not sure for how to implement that, thanks for anyone who may help me with this problem.

Comment: Actually I finally find the way to resolve this issue, we should use the first way I tried, but not in main.lua, in the place you want to call the download lua script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C++, you could call [`luaL_dofile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_dofile) with the path to your file directly, then just call the function the usual way.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way.